# Error while inserting data into database in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, syntax-error, android-sqlite

I'm getting error like this while inserting item details :

```
09-28 16:30:32.558 9471-9471/com.example.android.inventoryapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting quantity=1 name=Chocolate phone num=9112 price=5 supp name=Venu
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "num": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO inventory(quantity,name,phone num,price,supp name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

DATABASE HELPER is:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    String SQL_CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE =  "CREATE TABLE " + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
            + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_Product_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_PRICE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_Quantity + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, "
            + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + InventoryContract.InventoryEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_Phno + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";
    // Execute the SQL statement
    //COLUMN_USERNAME +  " TEXT "
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PRODUCTS_TABLE);
}
```

Contract class is:

```
 public final static class InventoryEntry implements BaseColumns{
    public final static String TABLE_NAME="inventory";
    public final static String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
    public final static String COLUMN_Product_Name="name";
    public final static String COLUMN_PRICE="price";
    public final static String COLUMN_Quantity="quantity";
    public final static String COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME="supp name";
    public final static String COLUMN_SUPPLIER_Phno="phone num";

}
```

logcat response is:

```
com.example.android.inventoryapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "num": syntax error
09-28 16:30:32.558 9471-9471/com.example.android.inventoryapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting quantity=1 name=Chocolate phone num=9112 price=5 supp name=Venu
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "num": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO inventory(quantity,name,phone num,price,supp name) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
         at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1341)
         at com.example.android.inventoryapp.CatalogActivity.insertpet(CatalogActivity.java:104)
         at com.example.android.inventoryapp.CatalogActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(CatalogActivity.java:118)
         at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
         at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:407)
         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Column names can't have spaces in them. If you want to use spaces, like you do with `phone num`, you should escape the names by surrounding them with double quotes (`"`):

```
INSERT INTO inventory("quantity", "name", "phone num", "price", "supp name") 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works..  :)  I changed my data base version to two and changed the column names...

Answer (score 1):

```
        Create a method and write the code to insert the data into table as below...

         public boolean insertPetition1(String cap_date, String cap_time, String image_str, String latitude, String longitude,
                                           String upload_status) {

                SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();

                 try {
                    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_IMAGE_PATH, image_str);
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_CAPTURE_DATE, cap_date);
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_CAPTURE_TIME, cap_time);
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);
                    contentValues.put(COLUMN_UPLOAD_STATUS, upload_status);

                    if (db.insert(MAIN_TABLE, null, contentValues) > 0) {
                        Log.e("Parameters", "Parameters:" + contentValues);
                        isInserted = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.v("TAG", e.toString());
                }
                return isInserted;
            }


    Call this method where ever you want to insert data in the tabel ....

    public void dbChanges() {
       DatabaseHelper1 databaseMain = new 
       DatabaseHelper1(OfflineAttendanceChildWithOutAuto.this);
       boolean status = false;

       status = databaseMain.insertPetition1(date, currentTime, encodedImage, latitude, longitude, "", "", "", awccode, "", "", mainaddress, usercode, "", "", "1");

                   databaseMain.close();
                }

It will work for sure try like this....
```